# Can I turn off Restlet access logging on the command line using some system property?

Tags: java, restlet

Is there a system property setting which (on the command line using the `-D` flag) turns off the access logging in Restlet?

I have a feeling this should be really simple, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/48-restlet/101-restlet.html

You should be able to pass in

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="/home/myApp/config/myLogging.properties
```

And in myLogging.properties set

```
org.restlet.level=OFF
```